# Remove Virtualbox's lower machine configuration bar in a running VM?

Tags: virtualbox

I'm running a VM in VirtualBox 3.2.4 in Full Screen.

At the bottom of my screen, there's a small toolbar from Virtualbox. When I'm using my mouse to change windows, sometimes this toolbar pops-up and annoys me because I don't want to edit my VM configuration, I was trying to use the application in my OS toolbar.

I want to use my machine in a way that it simply **forgets** it's a virtual machine **unless** I press the Host control combinatio (Right Control + Home) - I don't need a menu hanging out telling me that.

Is there a mode to run my VM or a configuration tweak to do what I want?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Power off the virtual machine.

Find the machine you want to change in the list of virtual machines.

Right click -> Settings

General -> Advanced Tab

Untick the checkbox "Show in fullscreen/seamless"